# App crashes on button click(intent)

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclick, action

I made a button on the activity bar that will move you to an other page named - Shop but when im pressing the button, my app is crashing.

here is the button code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.PAUSE:
            openPopUP();
        case R.id.SHOP:
            openSHOP();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here is the openSHOP action:

```
private void openSHOP() {
    mPlayer.pause();
    Intent Intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Shop.class);
    startActivity(Intent);        
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "You are at the shop";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();           
}
```

here is the shop class:

```
        package com.example.whitetap;

    import com.example.whitetap.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.SoundPool;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Shop extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
       private Button button1;
       private Button button2;
       private Button button3;
       private Button button4;
       private Button button5;
       private Button button6;
       private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.shoplayout);
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setOnClickListener(this);
     button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     button2.setOnClickListener(this);
     button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     button3.setOnClickListener(this); 
     button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
     button4.setOnClickListener(this);
     button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
     button5.setOnClickListener(this); 
     button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
     button6.setOnClickListener(this); 
    //music
     SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
     int iTmp = sp.load(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); 
     sp.play(iTmp, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify);
     mPlayer.start();
     mPlayer.setLooping(true); }

  public void onClick(View v) {  
  int id = v.getId();
  if (id == R.id.button6) {   
     mPlayer.pause();
     Intent Intent = new Intent(Shop.this, FirstActivity.class);
     startActivity(Intent);        
     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence text = "You went back to the game";
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
     toast.show();     
     }
     }
     }
```

logcat:

```
06-28 20:18:31.522: I/ViewRootImpl(7191): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
06-28 20:18:31.592: I/ViewRootImpl(7191): ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
06-28 20:18:31.602: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): pause
06-28 20:18:31.602: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-28 20:18:31.652: D/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): calling notify_player_state: 32
06-28 20:18:31.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
06-28 20:18:31.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): callback application
06-28 20:18:31.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): back from callback
06-28 20:18:31.662: I/ActivityManager(7191): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.whitetap time:94790790
06-28 20:18:31.662: D/AndroidRuntime(7191): Shutting down VM
06-28 20:18:31.662: W/dalvikvm(7191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d69e48)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191): Process: com.example.whitetap, PID: 7191
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.whitetap/com.example.whitetap.Shop}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3468)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3671)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3639)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.example.whitetap.FirstActivity.openSHOP(FirstActivity.java:104)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.example.whitetap.FirstActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(FirstActivity.java:95)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2644)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1095)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:118)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18525)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
06-28 20:18:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(7191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 20:18:41.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-28 20:18:41.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): unrecognized message: (8, 0, 0)
06-28 20:18:41.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): callback application
06-28 20:18:41.652: V/MediaPlayer[Native](7191): back from callback
06-28 20:18:41.662: V/AudioSystem(7191): ioConfigChanged() event 1, ioHandle 2573
06-28 20:18:41.662: V/AudioSystem(7191): ioConfigChanged() output 2573 closed
```

Why my app is crashing on click?

Comment: Please post the thrown exception.

Comment: @brummfondel is that what you meant?

Comment: Post your manifast.xml. As @brummfondel says below, your manifast.xml most likely does not contain that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception states:

"Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.whitetap/com.example.whitetap.Shop}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Did you specify the Shop class as activity in the manifest AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to declare your activity inside your  AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="activityName"
/>
```

Make sure the path and the package is correct